# lost in the middle of Nvidia installs

Tags: 14.04, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

My new system is:

```
EB1037
CPU: Intel® Celeron® J1900 (2.0ghz)
Graphic: NVIDIA® GeForce 820M 512MB
Memory: 8GB DDR3L at 1333MHz
Storage: 2.5" 320GB SATA II 
Wireless: Data Network 802.11 b/g/n
LAN: 10/100/1000/Gigabits Mbps
```

In order to install ubuntu 14.04, I use a pen-drive with modified nomodeset on the grub, once installed I need to run editing grub to nomodeset.

Once in there go to updates, and select in additional drivers Nvidia latest tested drivers, or updates, once applied, I cannot get further because system display error bbswitch dma issues.

As I understand this means X Server cannot switch to Nvidia drivers, I could not find any guide or examples with similar environment, if somebody could help me to get over this issues I will appreciate the help

Comment: Why would you install additional drivers in your installation media? Install the system first, then install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should use the drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories.
But because you are having problems ... the latest drivers might be better.
Install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers for the GEFORCE 820M card.
This time perform NVIDIA drivers installation by using a different method.

First uninstall the - partly - installed NVIDIA drivers.
Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears,

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password ... then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.
Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears,

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and password ... then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Comment: well thing is my installation could not start if I dont use nomodeset, on grub, I modify this on my pendrive, after install, I need to edit like you put it here but only nomodeset works, if I use noveau.modeset=0 I only got a black screen, and nothing not even a terminal.

Comment: @GuillermoJorgeMoreno : Did you really write it this way : noveau.modeset=0 ? The correct parameter is : nouveau.modeset=0 ! nomodeset is an alternative when nouveau.modeset=0 does not work. Did you get the NVIDIA drivers installed by following the instructions described in the answer ? Please report back. :)

Comment: Well, I did all form I could think of to solve this, so I give a shoot at win 7, to see what is inside, and full of surprises, the little box.
Using Win the box needs an Intel HD graphics, driver to be installed b4 Nvidia, and then in order to install Nvidia U need previously install .Net 4.5 or later.Further I found the box needs the chipset and a trusted engine from Intel driver, so go figure why does not work with ubuntu.
Will keep update later I have another issue with BT, on both Ubuntu and Win, hard anebla but soft disabled